# How do I reference the entire row when creating a new column in a data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` with more than 200 variables which are all binary. I want to create a new column in it that counts the difference between each row and a reference vector:

```
#Example
dt = data.table(
"V1" = c(1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0),
"V2" = c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0),
"V3" = c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0),
"V4" = c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0),
"V5" = c(1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0)  
)

reference = c(1,1,0,1,0)
```

I can do that with a small for loop, such as

```
distance = NULL
for(i in 1:nrow(dt)){      
  distance[i] = sum(reference != dt[i,])  
}
```

But it's kind of slow and surely not the best way to do this. I tried:

```
dt[,"distance":= sum(reference != c(V1,V2,V3,V4,V5))]
dt[,"distance":= sum(reference != .SD)]
```

But neither works, as they return the same value for all rows. Also, a solution where I don't have to type all the variable names would be much better, as the real data.table has over 200 columns

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `sweep()` with `rowSums`, i.e.

```
rowSums(sweep(dt, 2, reference) != 0)
 #[1] 2 2 2 2 4 4 3 2 4 3 2 1 3 4 1 3
```

**BENCHMARK**

```
HUGH <- function(dt) {
    dt[, I := .I] 
    distance_by_I <- melt(dt, id.vars = "I")[, .(distance = sum(reference != value)), keyby = "I"]
    return(dt[distance_by_I, on = "I"])
}

Sotos <- function(dt) {
    return(rowSums(sweep(dt, 2, reference) != 0))
}

dt1 <- as.data.table(replicate(5, sample(c(0, 1), 100000, replace = TRUE)))
microbenchmark(HUGH(dt1), Sotos(dt1))

#Unit: milliseconds
#       expr       min        lq      mean   median        uq       max neval cld
#  HUGH(dt1) 112.71936 117.03380 124.05758 121.6537 128.09904 155.68470   100   b
# Sotos(dt1)  23.66799  31.11618  33.84753  32.8598  34.02818  68.75044   100  a
```

Comment: To save it as a new column: `dt[, distance:=rowSums(sweep(.SD, 2, reference) != 0)]`

Comment: This solution is really nice, and works perfectly in the toy example. But for some reason I'm getting an error when applying to the real data: `Error in Ops.data.frame(x, aperm(array(STATS, dims[perm]), order(perm)),  : 
  list of length 3860579 not meaningful`. Any Idea why?

Comment: No idea. What is the structure of your data table? (`str(dt)`)

Comment: `rowSums(dt - as.data.table(as.list(reference))[rep(1, nrow(dt))] != 0)` seems to be a bit faster, if speed is an issue.

Comment: All numeric. I also tried changing both to all integer but no success. But thanks, this was useful already, I just need to expand the example to match what I have.

Comment: @Henrik I tried to add it in the benchmarking but it throws an error, `Error in Ops.data.frame(dt1, as.data.table(as.list(reference))[rep(1,  : 
  ‘-’ only defined for equally-sized data frames`

Comment: @Sotos OK. The `data.frame` parts of the error seem suspicious. It works here. `f <- function(dt) rowSums(dt - as.data.table(as.list(reference))[rep(1, nrow(dt))] != 0)`; `all.equal(Sotos(dt1), f(dt1))`, `TRUE`.

Comment: interestingly I didn't get such a big difference in my benchmark between your solutions.

Answer (score 7):

Another:

```
ref = as.list(reference)
dt[, Reduce(`+`, Map(`!=`, .SD, ref))]
```

*How it works.* So we're taking each vector column in `.SD` and comparing it to the single corresponding value in `ref`. The `!=` function is vectorized, so each element of `ref` is recycled out to match the length of each vector.

This `Map` call returns a list of TRUE/FALSE vectors, one for each column. When we add up TRUE/FALSE values, they are treated as 1/0, so we just need to add these columns up. This can be achieved by passing the pairwise operator `+` between the first column and the second; and then again between the result of that computation and the third column; and so on. This is how `Reduce` works. It might be more readable as

```
x = dt[, Map(`!=`, .SD, ref)]
Reduce(`+`, x, init = 0L)
```

which can be read as

- v = 0
- for each xi in x, update v = v + xi

See also `?Map` and `?Reduce`.

---

*Timings.* I'm modifying the benchmark data, since using integers seems a lot saner if the OP really has 0-1 data. Also, adding more columns since the OP says they have a lot. Finally, editing Hugh's answer to be comparable to the others:

```
HUGH <- function(dt, r) {
  dt[, I := .I] 
  res <- melt(dt, id.vars = "I")[, .(distance = sum(r != value)), keyby = "I"]$distance
  dt[, I := NULL]
  res
}

Sotos <- function(dt, r) {
  return(rowSums(sweep(dt, 2, r) != 0))
}

mm <- function(dt, r){
  colSums(t(dt) != r)
}

ff <- function(DT, r){
  DT[, Reduce(`+`, Map(`!=`, .SD, r))]
}

nr = 20000
nc = 500
dt1 <- as.data.table(replicate(nc, sample(0:1, nr, replace = TRUE)))
ref <- rep(as.integer(reference), length.out=nc)
lref = as.list(ref)

identical(HUGH(dt1, ref), ff(dt1, lref)) # integer output
identical(mm(dt1, ref), Sotos(dt1, ref)) # numeric output
all.equal(HUGH(dt1, ref), mm(dt1, ref))  # but they match
# all TRUE

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(times = 3, 
 HUGH(dt1, ref), 
 Sotos(dt1, ref), 
 mm(dt1, ref), 
 ff(dt1, lref)
)
```

Result:

```
Unit: milliseconds
            expr      min        lq     mean   median         uq       max neval
  HUGH(dt1, ref) 365.0529 370.05233 378.8826 375.0517  385.79737  396.5430     3
 Sotos(dt1, ref) 871.5693 926.50462 961.5527 981.4400 1006.54437 1031.6488     3
    mm(dt1, ref) 104.5631 121.74086 131.7157 138.9186  145.29197  151.6653     3
   ff(dt1, lref)  87.0800  87.48975  93.1361  87.8995   96.16415  104.4288     3
```

Comment: I love this answer but don't understand much of what is going on... ``+`, Map(`!=`` is the function being passed to `Reduce`? Could you elaborate a bit on how it works or give a link I can read?

Comment: @Fino :) Sure, I've added some explanation of Map and Reduce.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way:

```
mm <- function(dt){
  colSums(t(dt) != reference)
}

mm(dt)
# [1] 2 2 2 2 4 4 3 2 4 3 2 1 3 4 1 3
```

**benchmark**

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- as.data.table(replicate(5, sample(c(0, 1), 100000, replace = TRUE)))

identical(Sotos(dt1), mm(dt1))
# [1] TRUE

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(HUGH(dt1), Sotos(dt1), mm(dt1))
# Unit: milliseconds
#       expr       min         lq      mean     median        uq      max neval cld
#  HUGH(dt1) 85.542550 101.339416 129.71317 106.634169 112.66004 473.9380   100   b
# Sotos(dt1) 35.699128  42.677696 125.95430 180.302919 189.34098 377.9523   100   b
#    mm(dt1)  4.604986   7.002416  17.57238   9.819895  12.27015 165.1440   100  a
```

Comment: That is indeed interesting. I have no idea as to why the benchmarking is different.

Answer (score 2):

Melt the table then compare each group.

```
dt[, I := .I]  # Add a dummy id if one doesn't already exist
distance_by_I <- melt(dt, id.vars = "I")[, .(distance = sum(reference != value)), keyby = "I"]
dt[distance_by_I, on = "I"]
```